# How to remove children of jquery draggable item after dropped

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using a parent li element as the draggable, it's the only element I want dragged, but the sub ul and it's children still exist after the li has been dropped.  So the question is, once a draggable is successfully dropped, how to delete the children of the item that no longer exists (since I'm not reverting)
Simple list:

```
<ul>
  <li class="draggable">Some text</li>
    <ul>
      <li class="child">More text</li>
      <li class="child">More text</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
<ul>

<div class="droppable">This is the drop zone</div>
```

There is a fiddle for the code so far: 
http://jsfiddle.net/wkrdgumb/1/

Comment: Na, in the example, I want to keep the Candidates list item, I want to remove the other ul that was nested under it.  (in the example, it's the names Justin Woo and Aimee Bowen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture the context of the parent element within the `start` event. After the element has been dropped, you can then remove the element that was captured in the `start` event within the `stop` event:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/mmrra4cc/)

```
$(function () {
    var $context = $();
    $(".contact-group").draggable({
        revert: false,
        refreshPositions: true,
        drag: function (event, ui) {
            ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
        },
        start: function (event, ui) {
            $context = ui.helper.parent();
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            ui.helper.removeClass("draggable");
            ui.helper.removeClass("contact-group");
            $context.remove();
        }
    });
    $(".send_to").droppable({
        // ...
    });
});
```

Comment: Brilliant!  I knew I was missing something simple.